# Do ADC do averaging of the voltage between 2 samples?

Tags: voltage, adc, high-frequency

I'm using a 14bit ADC (on a Spectrum PCI acquisition card) at 500 Mhz, but this question is valid more generally.

Do ADC do some averaging of the voltage between 2 samples, or do they usually take the measurement super precisely when a clock tick happens?

If ADC typically have 2 mode of operations about this, what are the names of these modes? (so that I can research with the right keywords)

[image]

Comment: That can't be aswered as it depends on ADC type and what you mean by ADC; the ADC itself or if the system around it, either on analog side before ADC or digital side after ADC, or how the ADC itself work. Can you be more specific?

Comment: Here you can find info on this topic: [Types of A/D Converters - The Ultimate Guide](https://dewesoft.com/daq/types-of-adc-converters). FWIW, the most common types I've come in contact with are SAR and Delta-Sigma.

Comment: @Justme Here is the datasheet https://spectrum-instrumentation.com/dl/m4i44_datasheet_english.pdf and especially a diagram on page 12. Where should I look to find this information? Is there a keyword like "averaging ADC" or something like this to find this information?

Comment: All of the above, depending on what type of ADC you have, and whether you regard its filters / preamplifiers as part of the ADC system. 'this value' would be for a 'sampling ADC'.

Comment: @Seir I didn't find SAR or Delta-Sigma in https://spectrum-instrumentation.com/dl/m4i44_datasheet_english.pdf but I found "ADC differential non linearity", does the "differential" keyword help here?

Comment: @Basj: No, DNL, INL, etc. are just specifications for the accuracy of the ADC.

Comment: For a Digitizer like the one you've linked, I'd assume a Flash A/C converter.

Comment: The waveform diagram drawn is likely invalid input for an ADC directly, as generally, there is an analog anti-aliasing filter which removes frequencies that can't be represented at the sampling rate it runs (Fs/2). And in digital domain the system has further processing such as a boxcar filter for averaging or bandwidth limiter so it's not in the ADC part but in the system after it.

Answer (score 5):

Some types of ADCs like sigma delta will average the input signal, or rather, digitize it at a very high sample rate lowpass filter it in the digital domain. In this case each output sample does not represent the value of the input signal at some specific instant, but rather a much filtered version. This is very useful, as it gives these ADCs the ability to filter out all sorts of noise, but they are unable to sample the input signal at a specific time.

In other ADC types, like SAR, there is a sampling capacitor and a sampling switch. When taking a sample, the switch will close and connect the sampling capacitor to the input. Voltage on the sampling capacitor follows the input voltage, but it is also lowpass filtered due to input source impedance, switch impedance, sampling capacitor value, etc. This defines the **ADC Bandwidth**.

At the end of the sampling period, the sampling switch opens. This does not happen instantly, and the time it takes to open is specified as **[Aperture Time](https://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/mt-007.pdf)**, and it is much smaller than the sample duration. When the switch is fully open and the sampling cap is disconnected from the input, its voltage will be digitized. The actual voltage is somewhat of an average of the input voltage during the aperture time (but not the duration of the whole sample, or the time the switch is closed).

ADC Bandwidth can be much higher than half sampling rate. The bandwidth of your signal has to be lower than Fs/2 to avoid aliasing, but that doesn't mean it has to be centered on zero Hz. If the ADC has adequate bandwidth and aperture time, it is possible to sample a narrow band signal centered around a carrier frequency with a sampling frequency corresponding to twice the narrow band signal.

So basically, if it's a sampling ADC, it will somewhat average the input signal over the aperture time. The analog input filter placed before the ADC will also lowpass the signal.